# Raster Clipper doesn't appear in QGIS v3.16 or v3.2

Tags: qgis

There have been a couple of other posts about this from 3-4 years ago.

Running QGIS (3.16 and 3.2) under MacOS High Sierra (Mac mini Intel) and Big Sur (M1 Mac mini) The raster clipper tool doesn't appear, even with a re-installation. I have not done a full delete, re-install cycle.

One post suggested that the tool depends on the GDAL tools, which I cannot find in the Plugins list.

Advice and pointers welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `Menu Processing / Toolbox` and enter `raster clip` - then the available tools are listed, see:

[image]